# using ncrunch with asp.net core 1.0 wont build

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, ncrunch

I am trying to use ncrunch with asp.net core but ncrunch is showing my build are failing. Is there a way to run ncrunch in asp.net core for unit testing.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I've just hit the same issue.

Comment: the ncrunch team has not released a version for it